# C - Integer throwing out random value?

Tags: c

Currently I am writing a simple program in C that reads in values the user enters in a loop. For some reason, when I initialize the integer `a` I am given a random value as opposed to the value I specified. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char sName[10];
    int sTime;
    int a = 0;

    printf("%d", &a);

    printf("Please enter the name of your snail: ");
    scanf("%s", &sName);

    for(a = 10; a < 20; a = a + 1) {
        printf("%d", &a);
        printf("Please enter the %d time of your snail: ", &a + 1);
        scanf(" %d ", &sTime);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `&a` returns the ADDRESS of the variable (e.g. a pointer).

Comment: another mistake is that `" %d "` in the last scan should be `"%d"` (no spaces). And `&sName` should be `sName`.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
printf("%d", &a);
```

to this:

```
printf("%d", a);
```

`&a` is the address of `a` (and it's of type `int*`, so `%d` is the wrong format). `a` gives you the value of `a`.

You still need the `&` in `scanf(" %d ", &sTime);`; `scanf` needs the address of `sTime` so it knows where to store the value.

Answer (score 1):

You're printing the address of `a`. You don't want the `&` in there:

```
printf("%d", a);
```

You *do* want the `&` for `scanf()` because you need to tell that function where (at what address) to store the value.